# Probability calculation outcome

Tags: probability

For my maths classes I need to do a probability calculation and I have no idee how to do it.

If some one could put me on the right track I would really appreciate this.

In 38,46% of the time the outcome will be A
In 36,59% of the time the outcome will be B

What is the chance of situation A happening in combination with B?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have enough information to answer.  It could be that there are three mutually exclusive possibilities and that A and B never happen together.  It could be that every time B happens so does A and a little bit of the time A happens without B.  They probably expect you to think the events are independent and use the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Comment: A or B always happens, no 3rd factor. And they can never happen together. It's either A or B

Comment: The total probability has to be $1$, so it can't be always one of the two.

Comment: But how can that be than?

Comment: Lets say that they are players of a sport. Player A wins 38,46% of the times against other players. Player B wins 36,59% of the times against other players. When they play against each other, how much chance has player A to beat player B?

Comment: That is quite a different question that again doesn't have an answer. Are there any ties?  Are their past results against exactly the same set of opponents?  What is the chance a better player loses one game to a weaker player?  Please think about your question more clearly.

Comment: There are no ties, they played against the same set of players and are both the same level

Comment: In some games the better player is almost sure to win, so A's chance to beat B could be very high.  In American baseball a poorer team wins almost half the games against a better team, so it would be almost an even chance.  How can we tell?

Comment: Ross, would you mind opening a chat? I need to ask you something

Comment: I don't think you have the reputation to join a chat.  I have had that problem before.  You can just put it here